# How to add header and footer to a dataframe and save it as a textile in some location in scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a Json file and have created a dataframe as below.

```
val jsonDf=spark.read.json("file:///home/ubuntu/Desktop/jsondata")
```

Now I need to add header and footer to jsondf and save it as a textfile on HDFS?

```
jsonDf.write.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/ubuntu/filerJson") // This is to save the dataframe
```

How to add header and footer at the sametime?

Comment: what are the values of header & footer, can you add sample input json & output ?

Comment: @Srinivas - Header -"File starts here", Footer -"File ends here". Any random header and footer. I'm looking for how can we add them while writing as a file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` to combine all DataFrame.

`Note` - All DataFrame columns should be same & Column data type should be `string` if you are using `text source` from DataFrame.

```
scala> val headerDF = Seq(("=========== Header ==========")).toDF("value")
headerDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> val footerDF = Seq(("=========== Footer ==========")).toDF("value")
footerDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> headerDF.union(df.select(to_json(struct($"*")).as("value"))).union(footerDF).repartition(1).write.text("/tmp/hfd")
```